# varchar in execute immediate

Tags: oracle, plsql, execute-immediate

I'm using the following script pl/sql:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into TAB1(ID, CODE, TYPE, ORDRE) 
    select ''KEY'', ''KEY_LIB'', ''TYP_KEY'', 3 FROM dual
    where not exists(
                    select ID,CODE,TYPE,ORDRE
                    FROM TAB1
                    where TYPE=''TYP_KEY''
                    AND CODE =''KEY_LIB''
                    )';
```

And I'm getting the following error :

> 923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected

The error seems to be in the second line but I can't figure out what's wrong.
Can anyone help please ?

Comment: The generated code is fine and works for me (tip: display the dynamic string using dbms_output and test it on the command line). It appears the error is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does: `not exists (select id,code,type,ordre from ...`) - the exists operator doesn't care what you select. Also, you could omit the `select from dual` by selecting directly from `TAB1` (with an additional `rownum=1` predicate).

Answer (score 0):

Type is a keyword in Oracle. So, try with tablename.Type when type is a column name. Here is your revised query:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into TAB1(ID, CODE, TYPE, ORDRE) 
select ''KEY'', ''KEY_LIB'', ''TYP_KEY'', 3 FROM dual
where not exists(
                select ID,CODE,TYPE,ORDRE
                FROM TAB1
                where TAB1.TYPE=''TYP_KEY''
                AND CODE =''KEY_LIB''
                )';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better try it like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into TAB1(ID, CODE, "TYPE", ORDRE) 
select :KEY, :KEY_LIB, :TYP_KEY, 3 FROM dual
where not exists(
                select ID,CODE,"TYPE",ORDRE
                FROM TAB1
                where "TYPE" = :TYP_KEY
                AND CODE = :KEY_LIB
                )'
USING 'KEY', 'KEY_LIB', 'TYP_KEY', 'TYP_KEY', 'KEY_LIB';
```

Comment: If you quote the `TYPE` in the column list you will need to quote it in the `WHERE` clause as well I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Alternative Quoting Mechanism (''Q'') for String Literals](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CIREYU9EA54EOKQ7LAMZKRF6P.html), then you don't need double quotes. With this technique it is much easier to test queries manually (if it is needed). Btw, your query works fine.

```
BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
     q'[INSERT INTO tab1(id, code, type, ordre) 
        SELECT 'KEY', 'KEY_LIB', 'TYP_KEY', 3 
          FROM dual
         WHERE NOT EXISTS(
                  SELECT 1
                    FROM tab1
                   where tab1.type = 'TYP_KEY'
                     AND code      = 'KEY_LIB'
               )]';
END;
/
```